# Chimp / Cucumber intro tutorial steps not launching appropriately

Tags: meteor, cucumber, chimp.js

I'm following https://chimp.readme.io/docs/tutorial steps, trying to get chimp up and running.

here are the steps listed:

```
mkdir chimp-tutorial
cd chimp-tutorial
npm install chimp
mkdir features
chimp --watch
```

However the last cmd returns

*bash: chimp: command not found*

I just installed Java 8v73, Node.js ... I'm getting around to cmdline - if I understand it proper, I'm doing a local install, and i can see /node_modules/ in /Users/pierre/ and there's the /chimp/ folder.... 
but if I then try to launch it from there via *.../node_modules/chimp/bin/chimp.js --watch*

no browser gets launched... Why? (I don't have admin rights on the machine so trying to figure out how to work locally)

Comment: That looks interesting. I have not tried it, I think I will.

Comment: I was thinking it had to do with Chimp being a local install (no '-g' in the tutorial) but I am running into other issues. Trying to standalone selenium cmd I am not getting it to open a browser.... I did not have Java JDK installed, only JRE (and Selenium needs JDK). Baby steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Chimp without `-g`, you can still access is using `./node_modules/.bin/chimp`

See here for more details:
https://chimp.readme.io/docs/installation#section-local-installation

Answer (score 0):

It seem the intro steps are a little unclear - From a vanilla laptop you need to install a few extra programs to resolve the dependencies (in my case, I added java SDK on top of java JRE & Node.js)

As mentioned, the chimp install is local and not global - It keeps telling me the command is not valid when called from the /chimp-tutorial/ dir.

However, calling it from where I expected it (.../node_modules/chimp/bin/chimp.js --watch) launches it and produces the expected output

```
[chimp] Running...
selenium-standalone installation [====================] 100% 0.0s
```

and after some wait (took a good minute the first time I think) A chrome browser is launched (was getting errors, did $npm chromedriver install to fix) and more output shows on screen:

```
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m00.000s
```

Comment: That's good for people who try this but have similar errors. I tried it and it worked OK for me. Glad you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks for checking on it Dave. Did you use '-g' when you installed chimp?  Because following the steps I get "bash: chimp: command not found" when invoking chimp....